# Turning on an Android phone with broken power and volume buttons

Tags: power-on

I have a Oneplus Two phone which fell down in just the right (or wrong..) way a couple of years ago and the volume and power buttons were smashed. I managed to use it for a while just without letting run out of battery but eventually moved on to another phone. Now I'm trying to see if I can somehow revive it or if I should sell it for parts. I remember I did install some app (likely Gravity Screen) that would supposedly turn the phone on when moved, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The phone is otherwise charging just fine, I just can't turn it back on.

Comment: If the phone is really off no app can turn it on. Try to connect to a charger, some phones start booting with charger attached.

Comment: Unfortunately, while it does start charging, it doesn't power up when connected with a charger. Thanks for the info!